# Creating draggable icons in a listview in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm working on a PyQt program where I want to be able to have some objects, say shapes, in a 'toolbar' of sorts.  I would like the user to be able to click and drag an instance of one of these shapes from the toolbar to a main canvas (a QGraphicsView).

For the toolbar I was thinking of using a QListView which I could populate using a  QAbstractListModel.  However, I'm not sure how I can make the QListView hold only the icons of the shapes that I want... and second of all, how I can make the object icons draggable onto my main canvas.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a really broad question (probably two questions). Have you looked at the [Drag and Drop](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/dnd.html) docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this question contained some specific code examples with an existing direction, I could comment more specifically, but here is just some general points:

- Your QListView data does not need to specifically relate to the drag and drop issue, so you can populate it however you want: QListWidget, QListView + model, ../
- The important aspect is setting up drag methods on your QListX widget to set up an appropriate [QMimeData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmimedata.html) in the [QDrag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdrag.html). This is the important part that transfers the data to the drop site. You can have it send an image, or some reference to some data, for which the receiver can make use of.
- Set up a drop event on the graphics view to receive and check the mime type. Lets say you are just sending an image. You can receive it and add a pixmap item to your scene. Or maybe you are sending some internal reference like an id to a dictionary. It can be looked up and the data can be added to the scene in the form you want.

Refer to the general [Qt Drag and Drop docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/dnd.html). They are pretty much what you want.